How to resolve JacksonSupport Library Dependency Error
I have setup a project using the below sbt file:
name := "ElasticSearchService"
    
    version := "0.1"
    
    scalaVersion := "3.5.2"
    
    // Elastic4s dependencies
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-client-esjava" % "8.11.5",
      "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-core" % "8.11.5",
      "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-json-jackson" % "8.11.5"
    )
    
    // PostgreSQL dependency
    libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.3.1"
    
    // Spray JSON dependency
    libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.3.6"
    
    // Cask dependency
    libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "cask" % "0.9.4"
    
    // Elasticsearch dependencies
    libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.client" % "elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client" % "7.10.2"
    libraryDependencies += "co.elastic.clients" % "elasticsearch-java" % "8.5.3"
    
    // Logging dependencies
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.17.1",
      "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % "2.17.1",
      "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.32"
    )
    
    // Jackson dependencies
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.18.0",
      "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.18.0"
    )

This project relies on an ElasticSearch client and an API that is built overtop of that. I have followed various tutorials and documentation online and have begun using the cask framework for my API (https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/cask/) setup. When I run the project I get the errors below:
Total time: 13 s, completed Oct 29, 2024, 10:23:11 a.m.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sksamuel.elastic4s.JacksonSupport$
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ResponseHandler$.fromEntity(ResponseHandler.scala:44)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ResponseHandler$.fromResponse(ResponseHandler.scala:39)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.handlers.index.IndexHandlers$$anon$1.handle(IndexHandlers.scala:20)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticClient.execute$$anonfun$1(ElasticClient.scala:56)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:467)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.compute(ForkJoinTask.java:1726)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.compute(ForkJoinTask.java:1717)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$InterruptibleTask.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1641)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:507)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1458)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:2034)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:189)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: groupId [in thread "scala-execution-context-global-190"]
        at scala.collection.MapOps.default(Map.scala:289)
        at scala.collection.MapOps.default$(Map.scala:288)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:420)
        at scala.collection.MapOps.apply(Map.scala:176)
        at scala.collection.MapOps.apply$(Map.scala:175)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:420)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$.version$lzyINIT1(JacksonModule.scala:27)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$.version(JacksonModule.scala:26)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.version(JacksonModule.scala:44)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.version$(JacksonModule.scala:38)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.version(DefaultScalaModule.scala:21)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:881)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.JacksonSupport$.<clinit>(JacksonSupport.scala:11)
        ... 12 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sksamuel.elastic4s.JacksonSupport$
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ResponseHandler$.fromEntity(ResponseHandler.scala:44)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ResponseHandler$.fromResponse(ResponseHandler.scala:39)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.handlers.index.IndexHandlers$$anon$1.handle(IndexHandlers.scala:20)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticClient.execute$$anonfun$1(ElasticClient.scala:56)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:467)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.compute(ForkJoinTask.java:1726)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.compute(ForkJoinTask.java:1717)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$InterruptibleTask.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1641)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:507)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1458)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:2034)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:189)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: groupId [in thread "scala-execution-context-global-190"]
        at scala.collection.MapOps.default(Map.scala:289)
        at scala.collection.MapOps.default$(Map.scala:288)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:420)
        at scala.collection.MapOps.apply(Map.scala:176)
        at scala.collection.MapOps.apply$(Map.scala:175)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:420)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$.version$lzyINIT1(JacksonModule.scala:27)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$.version(JacksonModule.scala:26)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.version(JacksonModule.scala:44)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.version$(JacksonModule.scala:38)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.version(DefaultScalaModule.scala:21)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:881)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.JacksonSupport$.<clinit>(JacksonSupport.scala:11)
        ... 12 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sksamuel.elastic4s.JacksonSupport$
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ResponseHandler$.fromEntity(ResponseHandler.scala:44)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ResponseHandler$.fromResponse(ResponseHandler.scala:39)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.handlers.index.IndexHandlers$$anon$1.handle(IndexHandlers.scala:20)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticClient.execute$$anonfun$1(ElasticClient.scala:56)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:467)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.compute(ForkJoinTask.java:1726)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.compute(ForkJoinTask.java:1717)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$InterruptibleTask.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1641)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:507)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1458)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:2034)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:189)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: groupId [in thread "scala-execution-context-global-190"]

The error seems to be related to the Jackson library. But I'm not entirely sure what the issue is. The versions seem to be correct. Is there anything incorrect with my current setup to enable the proper libraries for my API and ElasticSearch?

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/933b5278e8f6d4600f1273332912abb5e8de51f5/src/main/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/JacksonModule.scala#L27 Jackson Scala module expects to read some metadata that should be present in the classpath. Any chance you are manipulating the classpath (fat JAR for instance)? Did you run a sbt dependencyTree to make sure all versions are aligned and you don't have conflicts?
